# Show * at proper column related to an integer column on database (fastreport and delphi XE4)?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe4, fastreport

I want to print a page using data from SQL database. I have an tinyint column (range:1-4). and have four columns in my fastreport page and want to sign proper column related to that column on database. How to do so?
  For example this is a sample page that I want to print :
[image]

I want to show * at proper position (column). At this example the database number for "America" is 1 so the star would be at first column and etc.
How can I do this using fastreport in delphi XE4? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is this PIVOT? I googled "fastreport Pivot" and "delphi pivot" but find nothing proper. Where can i find more detail or tutorial about that?
  I want this table in fastreport to print. The number in database (1-4) determines witch column to be stared.

Comment: `PIVOT` is a SQL function to basically turn row results into columns. If you can draft a SQL fiddle with the table structure, I can see if I can figure out the proper way to create the command.

Comment: Thank you SchmitzIT. PIVOT is amazing function. I read the syntax and  write my script.
 
SELECT *
FROM SHScores
pivot 
(
    SUM(Score)
    FOR Score
    IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) as TST

  if you post any answer I will sign it as answer. tnx.